# How to replace two words with two matching words from an array in Arabic JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arabic

I have the months of English in an array and also the Days of the week in an array.

I want to replace the English with the Arabic in the matching array indexes. This is my code. Clean and simple but it is not working. I am using two replaces.

```
// English
var en_months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];
var en_days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday']

// Arabic
var ar_months = ['كانون الثاني','شباط','آذار','نيسان','أيار','حزيران','تموز','آب','أيلول','تشرين الأول','تشرين الثاني','كانون الأول'];
var ar_days = ['الأحَد','الإثْنَين','الثَلاثاء','الأربَعاء','الخَميس','الجُمُعة','السَبْت']


// GO FOR IT
jQuery("span.date").text(function(i, val) {
    return val.replace(en_months, ar_months);
    return val.replace(en_days, ar_days);
});
```

This is the span. `<span class="date">Wednesday, October 7th, 2015</span>` There are a few on the page.

Comment: Can you expand on the "not working" part? If the `replace` part "does nothing", try with some random string - not Arabic. If *that* works, it's probably an encoding problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For replace you can use `RegExp`, in `RegExp` you can set pattern as string, that I've done in my example, I converted `en_months` to string with `.join` method, also you can see `indexOf` that returns the first index at which a given element can be found, for example if "October" there is in array it returns 9, and then by this index I get element from `ar_months` or `ar_days` and return this element from `.replace` method

```js
// English
var en_months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];

var en_days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday']

// Arabic
var ar_months = ['كانون الثاني','شباط','آذار','نيسان','أيار','حزيران','تموز','آب','أيلول','تشرين الأول','تشرين الثاني','كانون الأول'];
var ar_days = ['الأحَد','الإثْنَين','الثَلاثاء','الأربَعاء','الخَميس','الجُمُعة','السَبْت']

// GO FOR IT
$("span.date").text(function(i, val) {
    val = val.replace(new RegExp(en_months.join('|')), function (match) {
        return ar_months[en_months.indexOf(match)] || match;
    });
    
    val = val.replace(new RegExp(en_days.join('|')), function (match) {
        return ar_days[en_days.indexOf(match)] || match;
    });
    
    return val;
});
```

```css
.date {
   direction: rtl;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="date">Wednesday, October 7th, 2015</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over all the possible values and replace them one at a time.
And the execution of the function is stopped after the first `return ...`.

```
jQuery("span.date").text(function() {
    var text = val,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < en_months.length; i++) {
        text = text.replace(en_months[i], ar_months[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < en_days.length; i++) {
        text = text.replace(en_days[i], ar_days[i]);
    }

    return text;
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1ror3x52/)